# why it is called "extension of partial converse 2" GP1.4.4?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology, geometric-topology

The partial converse 2 is given below:

> [image]

And the question is given below:

> [image]

1-I am wondering why this problem considered as an extension of partial converse 2? could anyone answer this question for me please?

2-Also I know to solve 1.4.4  I should start by proving the second equality first because it is part of the first one but I do not know how to do this, could anyone help me in the proof please?

Also I have found 2 questions related to this part on this site, which are:

[GP 1.4.4 An extension of partial converse of preimage theorem.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437234/gp-1-4-4-an-extension-of-partial-converse-of-preimage-theorem)

And [Partial Converse 2 in Guillemin Pollack (Page 24)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2475697/partial-converse-2-in-guillemin-pollack-page-24)

In the first link I do not know the theorem that he applied, he called it "the domain-straightening theorem?" and I searched for it and did not found it , could anyone clarify this for me please?

Comment: If you take $Z=X$, you recover the first statement, so it's an extension.

Comment: what about the $Y$?

Comment: They changed notation.  In the first statement, $X$ is the ambient manifold.  In the extension, $Y$ is the ambient manifold.

Comment: What about the rest of my questions?@Matt

Comment: It's been a long time since I looked at G&P's Diff. Manifolds text, and don't have a copy on hand to check the various definitions.  If you would like a better exposition of the material presented, I suggest Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds.  His Chapter 5 deals with Submanifolds, and in particular, I believe the "Domain-Straightening Theorem" is most likely just a (local) version of the the Constant Rank/Submersion Level Set Theorem in Lee's text.

Comment: I think you should apply partial converse 2 twice to solve this problem, first to the second equality and second to the first equality  but I am not sure of the details of the application ..... correct @Matt ..... could you help us about the details of the second application of partial converse 2?