# Prove that the paraboloid in $R^3$, defined by $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 =a$ is a manifold if $a>0$. why does not $x^2 + y^2 -z^2 =0$ define a manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, geometric-topology

Prove that the paraboloid in $R^3$, defined by $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 =a$ is a manifold if $a>0$. why does not $x^2 + y^2 -z^2 =0$ define a manifold?

Could anyone give me a hint of the solution of this question?

**EDIT:**

I found this solution:

> [image]

But I need more details about why it is a manifold and why when $a = 0$ it is not, could anyone explain this to me in a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is $z = \pm \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. For a fixed $z$, this is a circle, with radius $|z|$. So this is a two sided cone; any neighbourhood of the point $(0,0,0)\in M$ can be disconnected by removing the point $(0,0,0)$, and so isn't homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb R^2$. For intuition about surfaces in $\mathbb R^3$, I reccomend spending some time with a plotter- observe the bad behavior at $0$.

[image]

Comment: How it is a two sided cone could you explain more please?

Comment: How any nbhd of (0,0,0) can be disconnected ..... could you explain more please?

Comment: Could you please try to answer this problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2948702/why-it-is-called-extension-of-partial-converse-2-gp1-4-4  please?

Comment: And why the other case is a manifold?

Comment: @hopefully I already gave the full explanation in words, perhaps you can try looking at this graph while reading.